# Xcode not recognizing any other view controller from other class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I thin something may have caused Xcode to start acting weird. In many of my .h files, I had different view controller objects for different classes. All of a sudden, Xcode now is giving me an error for almost ALL of them saying it doesn't recognize "thisViewController". The error is something like "thisViewcontroller is not recognized, did you mean UISplitViewController".

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? I know the code is correct (worked before) and I think it would be pointless to repost most of it/ all of it here

Thanks

Comment: Does the project build? Are these warnings or errors?

Comment: Are you `#import`'ing, `@class`'ing, and `@property`'ing each one?

Comment: Have you recently modified `#import` (or `#include`) statements?  This kind of error can be caused if you accidentally have headers that depend on each other.

Comment: It does not build unless I remove all the code that references other view controllers outside of their own class... every view controlled referenced outside gets an error saying it is not recognized in the header file even though the appropriate header file is imported

Comment: @KevinGrant Thats what I figured and I have messed with the #import but nothing that wasn't logical I believe...

Comment: Go over all of your classes and write down who imports who - you're bound to find a cycle there.

Comment: @stavash Sorry can you expand a little on that? What am I looking for exactly? A class missing an import that needed to be imported? Thanks

Comment: You're looking for an "import cycle", which means mutual dependance between two classes. If class A has an "#import ClassB.h" then class B can't have an "#import ClassA.h". It's not your problem 100% but it's worth investigating.

Comment: @stavash you were right. Please post what you explained above for future users and I will accept. Thanks to you and everyone for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for an "import cycle", which means mutual dependance between two classes. If class A has an "#import ClassB.h" then class B can't have an "#import ClassA.h".

Comment: What's the solution in the case that 2 classes need to know about each other?

Comment: @Matt it very much depends on the case at hand. Do you have a specific example?

Comment: It really doesn't depend on the case. Forward declare one of the classes like `@class ClassName` in the file that isn't `ClassName`.